# How to calculate sum of uniqe combinations in 2-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I am creating a function in C# to calculate the sums of the unique combinations of values in an Array.

I have a 2-dimensional array w/ the following values:

```
1  | 32  | 1024
2  | 64  | 2048
4  | 128 | 4096
8  | 256 | 8192
16 | 512 | 16384
```

For each row I select a column and then sum up the values, e.g:

```
(1)  | 32    | 1024
2    | (64)  | 2048
4    | (128) | 4096
8    | 256   | (8192)
(16) | 512   | 16384


1 + 64 + 128 + 8192 + 16 = 8401
```

What I want to do is to calculate this for all unique row and column combinations. As I see it there will be 3^5 = 243 unique sums to be calculated.

Does anyone have a smart solution to this? I have tried some variants myself but I can't get my head around this.

Kind regards,
Peter

Comment: I usually just brute-force my way through with recursion with something like this.

Comment: Can you provide few examples of non-unique combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slightly more math-y way to figure it out, rather than brute force.

Given that each value in a row will be summed `width` times for each of the other `height-1` rows, you can do the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] arr = new int[3, 5];
    int val = 1;
    int total = 0;
    //Both init the array with data, and get the sum of all elements
    for (int c=0; c<3; ++c)
    {
        for(int r=0; r<5; ++r)
        {
            arr[c,r] = val;
            total += val;
            //Console.Write("{0} ", val);
            val <<= 1;
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    //Do the math
    int b = arr.GetLength(0);
    int e = arr.GetLength(1) - 1;
    int power = (int)Math.Pow(b, e);
    total *= power;

    Console.WriteLine(total); //Outputs 2654127
}
```

Comment: This works when the numbers are exactly as in the example. I did understand the question different but seems Peter was looking for rhis. Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] values = new int[5][];
            values[0]= new int[] { 1, 32, 1024 };
            values[1] = new int[] { 2, 64, 2048 };
            values[2] = new int[] { 4, 128, 4096 };
            values[3] = new int[] { 8, 256, 8192 };
            values[4] = new int[] { 16, 512, 16384 };

            int[] result = values[0]; 

            for(int i = 1; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                result = Multiply2Arrays(result, values[i]);
            }
        }

        private static int[] Multiply2Arrays(int[] array1, int[] array2)
        {
            int[] result = new int[array1.Length * array2.Length];
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array2.Length; j++)
                {
                    result[counter] = array1[i] + array2[j];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```